# Windows 10 asking to verify my MS account after every reboot?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-account

I setup a new laptop with Windows 10 Pro, and signed in with an MS only account.  It works fine, but after every reboot it asks me to sign-in again to verify my MS account.  I do, and it works fine, until the next reboot.  Any ideas on how to get it to stop?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by unlinking my Microsoft account from my Windows account (switching it to a "local account" instead), rebooting, linking the Microsoft account back, and then rebooting again.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using another account.If problem still persists!Then add it as a trusted device.To do It FOLLOW:

1. Sign in with your Microsoft account to a Windows 10 PC that you want to add as a trusted device.
2. Open Settings, and click/tap on the Accounts icon.
3. Click/tap on Your account on the left side, and click/tap on the Verify link on the right side at the top.
4. Select how you would like to get your security code for verification, and click/tap on Next.
5. Enter the code you received, and click/tap on Submit.

This should do it!

Comment: thanks, but the laptop does show in my account's devices, and there's no Verify link on the Accounts screen.

Comment: Did you try signing out and signing in.

Comment: You are signed out whenever you reboot the computer, so yes.