# Windows 11 - How to stop "To see work results, please verify your account" in Start Menu

Tags: windows-11, user-accounts

Having fully disconnected from a work account (or so I thought), I find this verification popup keeps happening. How do I actually fully disconnect from the account it wants to verify?

I tried [the solution here](https://superuser.com/questions/1103137/windows-10-asking-to-verify-my-ms-account-after-every-reboot) of making my account local, rebooting, reconnecting then finally rebooting again, but that didn't work.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution given in the question (not the answer) [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1717809/how-to-remove-a-work-account-from-windows-11) worked. Posting this Q+A because I did not easily find it at first. (ie, this is a deliberate duplicate)

Under Account Settings, look up "Access work or school", NOT "Email & accounts".

Under "Access work or school", there will be an organisation which needs disconnecting.